# sentry permission denied error in node js : source map Integration

Tags: node.js, express, sentry

I am trying to implement sourcemap in my node js project but getting this error. My source maps are uploaded to my account but still my error causing file name is not showing .

In order to debug my event i run this command. sentry-cli --log-level=debug sourcemaps explain b5b6b44d8d6c45d89e85f70a574724ce and got this error
DEBUG   2023-07-17 19:00:09.260678885 +05:30 body: {"detail":"You do not have permission to perform this action."}
error: API request failed
caused by: sentry reported an error: You do not have permission to perform this action. (http status: 403)
blog refered https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/uploading/typescript/

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your Sentry Auth Token has the following permissions:

- org:read
- project:read
- project:releases

Use `sentry-cli login` to create a new token.